# Sqlite is a read only database error

Tags: server, sqlite

I want to run manic time server on my Ubuntu server but when I run manic time I get this error how can I solve this?

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 8: 'attempt to write a readonly database'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Shared.Storage.Sqlite.SqliteDatabaseConnection.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(String sql, DbQueryParameter[] parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Finkit.ManicTime.Shared.DatabaseRegistry.DatabaseRegistryTable.SetAsync(IDatabaseQueryable queryable, String key, String value, RandomSequence currentTimestamp, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Finkit.ManicTime.Shared.DatabaseInitialization.Sql.SqlDatabaseUpdater.LockDatabaseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Finkit.ManicTime.Shared.DatabaseInitialization.DatabaseInitializer.LockDatabaseAsync(IDatabaseUpdater updater, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Does the user you run the server as have write permission for the sqlite file?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I want to learn how I give permissions to these users or how I manage it